# What are the と, という, and の doing in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-の, particle-と

> 「帰ってきました！ただいまー！」声を張り上げて足を踏み入れる**と**、広がるのは地下室という響きとはかけ離れた生活臭**の**する小部屋だった。

I'm confused as to what と does in this sentence. Is it a quoting particle or conditional?

> 地下室という響きとは

I'm completely lost as to what this is supposed to mean

> かけ離れた生活臭**の**する小部屋だった。

Also is this の particle possessive?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. For this と, see [this post](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24523/using-%E3%81%A8-to-link-clauses-instead-of-%E3%81%A6) or [と❷接助-#1](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/154670/m0u/%E3%81%A8/). 3. The の indicates the subject. See [の❶格助-#2](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/171157/m0u/%E3%81%AE/) or [this post](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/how-does-the-%E3%81%AE-work-in-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AE%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E/12829#12829).

Comment: 2. Are you confused with the phrase 「～という+響き」, or 「～と+かけ離れる」?

Comment: I'm confused with 地下室という響き. Is it operating the same way as the という in 芝という犬?

Comment: 芝という犬 sounds "a dog 芝 by name" (or "a dog called 芝".) The construction looks similar, but I don't think the operation is the same. Any idea, @Choko?

Comment: Yes I also think the construction (or grammar?) is the same; in both of them the と is the quotative particle and the いう is the verb 言う. But the usage/meaning of という in 芝という犬 is [definition #1 「…と呼ばれている」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/52678/m0u/), and the という in という響き is closer to [#5「同格のものを指して」, eg 「大阪という都市」(the city of Osaka) 「犬という忠実な動物は人間の最良の友達だ」(That faithful animal the dog is man's best friend.)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/52678/m0u/). I think you can think of 地下室という響き as 『地下室』という言葉の響き (≒『地下室』という言葉から受ける印象, as in @eltonjohn's translation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

足を踏み入れると  when I stepped in

広がるのは (what I found) extended (in front of me) was

地下室という響き the impression given by the word "basement" (Caveat: this is not a verbatim translation.)

かけ離れた far from

生活臭のする小部屋 a small room with daily odour (I suspect this "odour" is figurative: the authour may have wanted to convey that the room was full of traces of daily life. But I need the context to be sure.)

Comment: The OP asked two specific questions that you don't have anything written specifically about in your answer...

Comment: @virmaior: It is true that I haven't *explicitly* done syntactic analysis, but I think the real objective of the appender is to comprehend the content (= semantics and pragmatics) rather than to grasp grammatical details.