# What function does とは have here? Is に omitted here?

Tags: grammar

> 不自由**とは**無縁の生活を捨てて、神様は不便極まるこの世界にのめり込んでいった。

Is it defining something?

Also in the second part, is the に particle before the intransitive verb omitted or does it not require it?

> 神様は**不便極まる**この世界にのめり込んでいった。

Thanks!

Comment: I just edited my post for your 2nd question -- tell me if this helps answer it

Comment: The とは is the same as in 地下室という響き**とは**かけ離れた in [your other question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25291/very-confused-with-this-sentence). You can rephrase them as ～ **からは**無縁の, ～ **からは**かけ離れた.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

とは is used descriptively here, much like 〜とは違う. In this sentence, you should be looking at とは無縁 all together.

> 不自由*とは無縁*の生活 "life *free from* inconvenience"

Not as easy to translate to English, but easy to see from examples how it's used in Japanese (see http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/159809/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF/). It's a combination of the particles と and は

As for the 2nd part you added after I initially posted, no, に isn't being excluded here. Expressions which take 〜極まる don't take に between them and the 極まる part. For example:

> 進退極まる
>
> 迷惑極まる
>
> 感極まって言葉も出ない

Comment: 「無縁」を辞書で調べてみましょう。 [とは無縁 Weblio和英](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E7%84%A1%E7%B8%81%22) "free from~" / "not related to ~" ・ [無縁 goo国語辞典](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/214520/m0u/) eg「我々とは―の出来事」

Comment: I think 極まる in the first example is used differently form the second and the third. For the record, 進退極まる = "be in checkmate", "迷惑極まる" = it is an extreme annoyance" and 感極まって言葉も出ない = "overwhelmed to utter a word".

Comment: @eltonjohn The examples are more to show how expressions don't take 'ni'  rather than focusing on meaning

Comment: @Sqrtbottle: <The examples are more to show how expressions don't take 'ni' rather than focusing on meaning> I know. But I thought some people may get confused.

Comment: After checking these dictionaries do you still think the とは in 不自由とは無縁の生活 is quotative と + topical は? Compare: 「～とは違う」

Comment: Okay, so the と in とは無縁 is ❶-#3 "比較の基準を表す。「君の―は比べものにならない」「昔―違う」", meaning "from~". The と in the defining とは to indicate a topic of discussion is ❶-#2 "引用の「と」" on [goo国語辞典「と」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/154670/m0u/%E3%81%A8/). Also refer to #1 and #2 on [goo国語辞典「とは」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/159809/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF/)

Comment: Why the downvote at 23pm, after the last edit at 21pm?